# Is there a way to block the Verizon tracking cookie using Privoxy?

Tags: dd-wrt, cookies, privoxy

I'm using Privoxy on a DD-WRT router to do ad blocking on my local network. Is there modification I can make to the Privoxy configuration to block the infamous Verizon tracking cookie?

Comment: Verizon will soon allow you to opt out of their tracking cookie, see: http://nyti.ms/1yLwifT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a Verizon customer, but its my understanding that Verizon are adding the request one it hits their network so there is nothing you can do to stop a tracking cookie from being added on your router.   (I suspect you may be able to opt out of this evil).

Unless you can opt-out with Verizon (I'd suggest opting out via the use of another ISP if thats an option for you) the best solution may be to use a VPN to bypass Verizons grasp altogether.

You might be able to mitigate a bit of the damage caused by using something like HTTP Everywhere which tries to convert all requests to HTTPS - I'd imagine that Verizon are unable to modify the packets sent across an HTTPS request, so where sites use HTTPS - and thanks to Snowden lots of big sites are turning it on, this might help.

Comment: I had a feeling that was the case but I wanted to make sure. It looks Verizon is backing down on this a bit, which is great - http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2015/02/verizon-will-now-let-users-kill-previously-indestructible-tracking-code/